# Merge four vector layers into one shapefile and keep the symbology

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector-layer

I am using QGIS.
I have four vector layers, they are all separately categorized and have a certain symbology. My goal is a shapefile containing all four layers and not losing the symbology. I already tried `vector -> data management tools -> merge vector layers... didn't keep the look I wanted. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to recreate the symbology after merging the data. Since you probably categorised the layers using different fields, you need to resort to rule based symbology.

Answer (score 4):

You can copy-paste the symbols.

Merge the layers to a single one, make sure there is a field to discriminate the records so they can be properly styled.

Create a `rule based` symbology for the new layer.

For each original layer, go to the symbology and, provided they are `single symbol`, convert them to `rule based` symbols.

Right click the symbol, `copy symbol`

Go to the new layer, create a new rule targeting the proper records, right click on the symbol, `paste symbol`.

[image]